# javaFX: how to Set picture size in CSS

Tags: javafx

Does anyone know why it is not possible to change the size property using something like "-fx-pref-width"?

I want to do something like this: 
root.setPrefWidth(500);

I tried: 
root.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 500;");but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion/explanation/another way to do it in CSS? How do you specify the size when you are using CSS?

Comment: You are setting preferred size of your root pane, and your title of this question says you want to set size of your picture. What exactly want to do ?

Comment: Sorry, Actually i want set a picture size in css :) I heard this will be done in jre 8?